# Passing Edit uicontrol string to callback of another uicontrol in Matlab

Tags: matlab, callback

I wrote a code like this in Matlab:

```
function[] = gui_function()
window.value1 = uicontrol('style', 'edit', ...
                          'string', '5', ...
                          'callback', @is_number);
window.computeButton = uicontrol('style', 'push', ...
    'callback', {@test_script, str2double(get(window.value1, 'string'))});
end

function[] = test_script(varargin)
value1 = varargin{3};
end
```

I want to pass the text from Edit uicontrol to Button's callback. When I do it as following, the value that is passed is an old value that is set when declaring the uicontrol. 
So ie. I run the GUI and have a value of 5 in the edit. I overwrite it to be 20, but after pushing the button, the value that is being passed is still 5

What is wrong in this approach? How can it be done differently?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best option when working with GUIs is to use the handles structure of the GUI, in which every uicontrols are stored along with their associated properties, in addition to (that's the cool part) whatever you want to store in it, like variables for instance.

So I modified you code a bit to make use of the handles structure. I'm not entirely clear as to what you want, but in my example the pushbutton is used to update the content of a second edit box with the content of the 1st edit box. That's very basic, but it should help you get a feel of handles and the handles structure. If something is unclear please let me know!

```
function gui_function()


ScreenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');

handles.figure = figure('Position',[ScreenSize(3)/2,ScreenSize(4)/2,400,285]);


handles.Edit1 = uicontrol('style', 'edit','Position',[100 150 75 50], ...
    'string', '5');

handles.Edit2 = uicontrol('style', 'edit','Position',[100 80 75 50], ...
    'string', 'Update me');

handles.computeButton = uicontrol('style', 'push','Position',[200 100 75 75],'String','PushMe', ...
    'callback', @PushButtonCallback);


guidata(handles.figure, handles); %// Save handles to guidata. Then it's accessible form everywhere in the GUI.

function PushButtonCallback(handles,~)

handles=guidata(gcf); %// Retrieve handles associated with figure.

TextInBox1 = get(handles.Edit1,'String');
set(handles.Edit2,'String',TextInBox1); %// Update 2nd edit box with content of the first.

%// Do whatever you want...
guidata(handles.figure, handles); %// DON'T forget to update the handles structure
```

You could customize this GUI by adding your function callback (test_script) in the same way I implemented the PushButtonCallback. Hope I understood what you wanted :)

Comment: Great! I was looking for something like that :) I guess that what I needed was this line:
`guidata(handles.figure, handles);`

Comment: great then! Yep that's the important line; use it whenever you change something into the handles structure and you need to update it. Notice that I changed your notation from 'window...' to 'handles...' but its the same altogether. :)